# How can avoid "Active desktop recovery" error in windows domain client machine?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

How can avoid "Active desktop recovery" error in windows client machine. This is mainly in IE7 installed client machines. Common desktop wallpaper replaced with this white error screen. Any fix for eliminate this?

Please help on this

Thanks

Comment: What OS are they running? I haven't seen that error since Windows 2000.

Comment: Windows Domain server having Windows 2008 and in client machine having windows xp prof

Answer (score 1):

Active Desktop wall papers are a nightmare and should be disabled.  It's a CPU hog and just a pain to deal with.

Comment: Active Desktop != Active Directory

Comment: True, it should have said Active Desktop which is now does.